# How to create on DAO class for all table/beans operation(insert )?

Tags: java, design-patterns

Is it posible to build a  common DAO class for different beans/tables?
Currently I am creating different DAO classes for each different table like: `CustomerDAO`, `EmployeeDAO`, `StudentDAO`.

Comment: Yes you can do that.

Comment: Yes you can. But having different DAO makes them more focused and specific in my opinion and will make your code readable and easy to maintain if it grows.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

How ?

This is Base DBO class for all your CustomerDBO, EmployeeDBO, StudentDBO.

```
public class BaseDBO {
}
```

Now, each of your DBO will be like this,

```
public class CustomerDBO extends BaseDBO {}
public class EmployeeDBO extends BaseDBO {}
public class StudentDBO extends BaseDBO {}
```

Write all the common methods in BaseDAO like

```
public class BaseDAO<T extends BaseDBO> {

    void create(T t){}
    void update(T t){}
    void delete(T t){}
}
```

Now on specific DAO looks like

CustomerDAO,

```
public class CustomerDAO extends BaseDAO<CustomerDBO> {
}
```

Now, for CustomerDAO contains all the methods which are common for DAO.

Similarly for StudentDAO, EmployeeDAO.

Hope this helps !!

Comment: You actually don't need to have your entities (what you call DBO here) extends a `BaseDBO`. You can have your `BaseDAO`just take `T`. `public class BaseDAO<T>`

Comment: @Matt, Funda is, If I have common columns like id/creation time, I can use this Base class to define them - not to make DBO to look clumsy. For this particular scenario to define the common DAO, it is not required - I agree to that point.